# How do I locate errors that are logged in the Event Viewer?

Tags: c++, mfc, event-viewer

I am using **Windows 10** and was running my application that I have been developing.

All of a sudden it crashed with no warning. It has been a very stable application and this behaviour is out of character. At the time all I was doing was moving the mouse.

I decided to look in the **Event Viewer** to see if there was anything there.

Event viewer **entry 1**

[image: Event viewer entry 1]

Event viewer **entry 2**

[image: Event viewer entry 2]

I notice that there was a .NET Runtime error at the same time as my application crashed. Interestingly, my application is developed with **Visual C++ MFC** and thus I am not working with the **.NET Framework**. Confused.

I don't know what all those numbers mean in the log. Is there anything I can do to use this to identify what happened? I am using **Visual Studio 2015**.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If the errors are related, I would assume, that some .NET module was injected into your application (remote thread, AppInit_Dll, gobal hook), that caused an access violation which was passed on to your application. Difficult to get any more information out of the event log after the fact. You could run your application and investigate all modules that are mapped into the process.